# Can we burninate [microsoft-certifications]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[microsoft-certifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-certifications)

I just saw this tag in a question regarding which certification path to follow, which was rapidly closed as off-topic.

I went ahead and removed this tag from 12 out of the 15 questions that had it (most closed as off-topic, some were actually [app-certification-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-certification-kit) related).

There are now only these 3 questions left:

- [Exam 70-483 programing in C# still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633394/exam-70-483-programing-in-c-sharp-still-valid) (already deleted)
- [Exam 70-483 programing in C# still valid for MCSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437777/exam-70-483-programing-in-c-sharp-still-valid-for-mcsa) (already deleted)
- [Microsoft Certification 483 vs 70-483 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273857/microsoft-certification-483-vs-70-483) (already deleted)

All these remaining questions are, by no doubt, off topic. Since the flag is also off topic, can we burninate it?

EDIT:

Now there are no more questions tagged with [microsoft-certifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-certifications)

Comment: "burninate" means "remove tag from all questions", so you've basically ***already done this***. Usually, the order is reversed, and you ask the meta question first.

Comment: I've flagged the first as off-topic and the second as a duplicate.

Comment: I wonder if there should be a separate community for this, or if there is one to which we could migrate certification questions?

Comment: @Hack-R That'd be very interesting indeed

Comment: @Hack-R you can back [IT Certifications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104336/it-certifications) over at Area 51.

Comment: I just re-tagged the last question adding [tag:c#] and removing [tag:microsoft-certifications].

Comment: Uncertify [microsoft-certifications]?

Comment: Issue [microsoft-certifications] death certificate?

Comment: If I cared enough, I'd ask a [meta-tag:burnination-request] for [tag:team] and [tag:collaboration].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this has been done, it can be considered closed.