# Ambiguous Tag [mcts]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

According to [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/how-should-ambiguous-tags-be-dealt-with), ambiguous tags should be discussed on Meta first.

I think the [mcts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcts) seems to be a bit ambiguous. The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mcts/info) says that the tag is about:

> Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist
>
> The Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist (MCTS) certifications are designed to help validate skills on the features and functionality of Microsoft technologies.

The [list of questions with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcts) contains some older questions that are indeed about this topic. However, the four most recent questions in this tag (which is every single question with the tag since 2015) instead use it as the acronym for the "Monte-Carlo Tree Search" algorithm, which is one of the most popular tree search algorithms in Artificial Intelligence (in particular for game-playing).

I'd argue that this MCTS algorithm definitely deserves its own tag, since many other algorithms that are commonly used in similar domains (games) also have their own tags, like `minimax` and `alpha-beta-pruning`.

I don't know if the best solution would be to simply repurpose the `mcts` tag and only use it for this algorithm (since the last question tagged with `mcts` that was actually about the Microsoft thing was back in 2014), or if a new tag should be created for the algorithm instead (for example, `monte-carlo-tree-search`)?

Comment: I would suggest adding `monte-carlo-tree-search` and make `mcts` a synonym of that. I can't imagine an on-topic question about an MCTS certification.

Comment: I [already asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351856/can-we-burninate-microsoft-certifications) for burnination of `microsoft-certification`, so it would make sense to burninate any question related to the MS certification

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, can you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest adding [monte-carlo-tree-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monte-carlo-tree-search) and make [mcts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcts) a synonym of that.

I can't imagine an on-topic question about an MCTS certification.

We'll need to clean up the current questions with [mcts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcts).

Comment: I've already created the monte-carlo-tree-search tag by editing one of the old mcts questions to switch over to the new tag. I do not yet have 2K rep though, so I cannot edit them all directly (would require others to accept all my edit suggestions afterwards), probably better if someone with > 2K rep does that. I can provide proper information about Monte-Carlo Tree Search on the tag's wiki though, will try to do that soon

Comment: Sounds good @Dennis. We should probably make sure that everyone gets a chance to see the question before we start editing questions. You may want to enlist the help of the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers); take a look at [that room's FAQ first](https://socvr.org/). My review hat thanks for waiting on doing the edits :).

Comment: Cleaned up [mcts], the tag wikis, and then syn'd it to [monte-carlo-tree-search]. (cc @DennisSoemers)